# Customize breaks and labels in ggscatterstats

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

I've used `ggscatterstats` in `ggstatsplot` package to plot a correlation plot with density plots in the margins, however I don't know how to customize the breaks of the plot, I've tried using `scale_x_continuous` to change the breaks and labels like in `ggplot2`, but it doesn't work. Appreciate for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify `ggscatterstats` if you are setting `marginal = TRUE` since the output object is no longer of class `ggplot`. If you set it to `FALSE` though, you can customize the plot with `ggplot2` functions.

For example-

```r
set.seed(123)

ggstatsplot::ggscatterstats(
  data = ggplot2::msleep,
  x = brainwt,
  y = sleep_total,
  xlab = "Brain weight (in kilograms)",
  ylab = "Total amount of sleep (in hours)",
  label.var = "name",
  label.expression = "brainwt > 0.0125",
  title = "Mammalian sleep",
  marginal = FALSE,
  type = "robust"
) + # further modifications with `ggplot2`
  ggplot2::geom_rug(sides = "b") +
  ggplot2::scale_x_log10()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-11-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, I need to plot marginal plots and this is why I use `ggscatterstats`, is there any way to modify breaks and labels while marginal plots are enabled?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, this is not possible. At least not in its current avatar. The only (painful) solution I can think of is looking at the base code for `ggscatterstats` and modifying it to your liking: https://github.com/IndrajeetPatil/ggstatsplot/blob/master/R/ggscatterstats.R.